# Polarization of a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $f\in K[V]_d$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ on the vector space $V$ over the field $K$ where char$(K)=0$. It is well-known that there is an isomorphism $$
\pi : K[V]_d\rightarrow Sym^d(V^*)\subseteq (V^*)^{\otimes m}
$$ i.e. $f$ can be seen as a multilinear function $$ f:\times_{i=1}^d V\rightarrow K$$

Now assume that $V=W^{\oplus m}$. From the coordinate description of the polarization, it seems like $f$ can be further seen as a multilinear function $$ f: \times_{i=1}^{md} W\rightarrow K$$ However I cannot write this map without coordinates.

> Question : Is there a natural embedding $K[W^{\oplus m}]_d\rightarrow (W^*)^{\otimes dm}$